# Calculus question on application of the quotient rule

Tags: calculus

The question is using quotient rule, find and simplify $\large \frac{dE}{d\theta}$ for
$$
E(\theta)= \frac{\theta-u\theta^2}{u+\theta}
$$

My try:
$$
\frac{(1-2u\theta)(u+\theta)-(\theta-u\theta^2)}{(u+\theta)^2}
$$

Is there any more simplification?

Comment: Clarify, please. Are those $u$s or $4$s in the first line? And in the third line did you mean $2\cdot 4\theta$ rather than $24\theta$? Please use LaTeX markup, by the way.

Comment: I fixed it, thanks for notifying me :)

Comment: You got the right answer. Just try reducing it if possible.

Comment: Open the brackets and you'll get $\frac {u-2u^2\theta-u{\theta}^2}{(u+\theta)^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{d\theta}E(\theta)=\frac{d}{d\theta}\frac{(\theta-u\theta^2)}{u+\theta}=-u\frac{(2u\theta+\theta^2-1)}{(u+\theta)^2}$$

Simplification is relative, what one considers "simple" another might consider complex. The derivative of $E$ with respect to $\theta$ can be denoted by an endless number of expressions.

One could ask why you even need to bother with manipulating that expression, why not just write it's derivative as $E'$? Is that not simpler?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is more simplification. You should expand the numerator and see what terms cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding the numerator's factors and gathering like terms gets the expression in its most compact form of:

$$E'(\theta)=\frac{u-2u^2\theta-u\theta^2}{(u+\theta)^2}$$

Well, you could then expand it by partial fractions, to get three simple quotients where $u$ only appears on their denominators (if at all).

$$E'(\theta)=-2\theta + \frac{3 \theta^2+1}{\theta+u} - \frac{\theta(\theta^2+1)}{(\theta+u)^2}$$

But is that simpler?